# Shopify App development issue- uninstall hook get fired anonymously

Tags: shopify-app

I have started on shopify app development, however my uninstall hook that I have registered on app installation fires anonymously. Please confirm how to resolve this, I have sent headers as well in response which is needed but the hook fires any time,

here is the code for uninstall function:

```
public function appuninstall() {
 header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
 $session = new Session(new NativeSessionStorage(), new AttributeBag()); 
 $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); $shop = $request->query- 
 >get('shop');
 $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Stores::class); 
 $store = $repository->findOneBy(['name' => $shop]);
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
 $em->remove($store);
 $em->flush();
 $session->remove('shop'); 
}
```

And I have registered this webhook in my redirect url function. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Can you post code here itself. if a link breaks in future, it  wont be helpful for new users.

Comment: Sure, here is the code for uninstall function:
    public function appuninstall() {
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        $session = new Session(new NativeSessionStorage(), new AttributeBag());
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $shop =  $request->query->get('shop');  
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Stores::class);
        $store = $repository->findOneBy(['name' => $shop]);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($store);
        $em->flush();
        $session->remove('shop');
    }

Comment: Do you know why this issue is coming ?

Comment: I did not get your question. Do you want to say that this webhook is firing without happening uninstallation? or you can not bifurcate that for which store it has been triggered.